# Gray screen with cross cursor in TightVNC

Tags: vnc-server, tightvnc

I am trying to VNC to a Ununtu 16.04 from windows 10. I am getting a textured gray screen with cross cursor.[image]

Below is my log file:

```
Xvnc Free Edition 4.1.1 - built Feb 25 2015 23:02:21
Copyright (C) 2002-2005 RealVNC Ltd.
See http://www.realvnc.com for information on VNC.
Underlying X server release 40300000, The XFree86 Project, Inc


Wed Aug 17 14:42:46 2016
 vncext:      VNC extension running!
 vncext:      Listening for VNC connections on port 5902
 vncext:      created VNC server for screen 0
error opening security policy file /etc/X11/xserver/SecurityPolicy
Could not init font path element /usr/X11R6/lib/X11/fonts/Type1/, removing from list!
Could not init font path element /usr/X11R6/lib/X11/fonts/Speedo/, removing from list!
Could not init font path element /usr/X11R6/lib/X11/fonts/misc/, removing from list!
Could not init font path element /usr/X11R6/lib/X11/fonts/75dpi/, removing from list!
Could not init font path element /usr/X11R6/lib/X11/fonts/100dpi/, removing from list!
Could not init font path element /usr/share/fonts/X11/75dpi/, removing from list!
Could not init font path element /usr/share/fonts/X11/100dpi/, removing from list!

Wed Aug 17 14:43:07 2016
 Connections: accepted: 0.0.0.0::64580
 SConnection: Client needs protocol version 3.8
 SConnection: Client requests security type VncAuth(2)

Wed Aug 17 14:43:10 2016
 VNCSConnST:  Server default pixel format depth 24 (32bpp) little-endian bgr888
 VNCSConnST:  Client pixel format depth 24 (32bpp) little-endian rgb888
```

My xtartup file looks like:

```
#!/bin/sh

# Uncomment the following two lines for normal desktop:
unset SESSION_MANAGER
exec /etc/X11/xinit/xinitrc

[ -x /etc/vnc/xstartup ] && exec /etc/vnc/xstartup
[ -r $HOME/.Xresources ] && xrdb $HOME/.Xresources
xsetroot -solid grey
vncconfig -iconic &
x-terminal-emulator -geometry 80x24+10+10 -ls -title "$VNCDESKTOP Desktop" &
x-window-manager &
```

I have searched internet thoroughly and have tried a lot of things suggested, but nothing does what I am looking for. If I comment the last two lines in the xstartup file, I get a smoother version of this gray screen with 3 check boxes on top-left corner. What I am looking for is a GUI as if I am directly using that machine.

Edit:
I have checked; `/etc/X11/xinit/xinitrc` is installed. Following is the list of x11* packages that are on the system:

```
root@sonu-virtual-machine:/etc/X11/xinit# dpkg -l | grep x11*
ii  dbus-x11                              1.10.6-1ubuntu3                                             amd64        simple interprocess messaging system (X11 deps)
ii  libselinux1:amd64                     2.4-3build2                                                 amd64        SELinux runtime shared libraries
ii  libspeex1:amd64                       1.2~rc1.2-1ubuntu1                                          amd64        The Speex codec runtime library
ii  libwebpmux1:amd64                     0.4.4-1                                                     amd64        Lossy compression of digital photographic images.
ii  libx11-6:amd64                        2:1.6.3-1ubuntu2                                            amd64        X11 client-side library
ii  libx11-data                           2:1.6.3-1ubuntu2                                            all          X11 client-side library
ii  libx11-protocol-perl                  0.56-7                                                      all          Perl module for the X Window System Protocol, version 11
ii  libx11-xcb1:amd64                     2:1.6.3-1ubuntu2                                            amd64        Xlib/XCB interface library
ii  libxkbcommon-x11-0:amd64              0.5.0-1ubuntu2                                              amd64        library to create keymaps with the XKB X11 protocol
ii  pulseaudio-module-x11                 1:8.0-0ubuntu3                                              amd64        X11 module for PulseAudio sound server
ii  signon-ui-x11                         0.17+16.04.20151125-0ubuntu1                                amd64        Single Sign-on UI
ii  x11-apps                              7.7+5+nmu1ubuntu1                                           amd64        X applications
ii  x11-common                            1:7.7+13ubuntu3                                             all          X Window System (X.Org) infrastructure
ii  x11-session-utils                     7.7+2                                                       amd64        X session utilities
ii  x11-utils                             7.7+3                                                       amd64        X11 utilities
ii  x11-xkb-utils                         7.7+2                                                       amd64        X11 XKB utilities
ii  x11-xserver-utils                     7.7+7                                                       amd64        X server utilities
```

Edit 2:
I checked -- file `/etc/X11/xserver/SecurityPolicy` is not present. I searched online. It seems a lot of others had this problem, but no solutions are there.

Comment: It means `exec /etc/X11/xinit/xinitrc` failed to execute. If it did, it won't go thru the next lines. Make sure `/etc/X11/xinit/xinitrc` exists. Kindly update your post and include all `xorg-x11-*` packages that are currently installed,

Comment: @alvits, I have updated the question.

Comment: You need to install `xorg-x11-server-Xorg` and at least 1 of the following desktop managers, `gdm`, `kde`, `wdm` or `xorg-x11-xdm`. If Ubuntu's packaging is good, it should pull all the dependencies.

Comment: I have exactly the same problem. None of these advices works

Comment: I have the same problem. Did someone resolved this ?